# Can't cover DMLException with my test

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, exception, dmlexception

I'm trying to cover my Exceptionm But I don't know. how to do this. When I try to insert a record without Required fields, I get the `System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:` error while running test.

```
public void updatingHelper(List<Tool__c> allTools){
    List<Gear__c> gearsToUpdate = new List<Gear__c>();
    Map<Id, Gear__c> mapGears = new Map<Id, Gear__c>();
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Tool__c tool : allTools){
    oppIds.add(tool.Opportunity__c);
}
Map<Id, Opportunity> opportunitiesMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
    [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Clients__c, StartDate__c, Opportunity__c FROM Tools__r WHERE DAY_ONLY(StartDate__c) >=: Date.TODAY()),
     FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : oppIds]
);   
List<Gear__c> actualGears = [SELECT Id, Clients__c, FinishDate__c, Tool__r.Opportunity__c FROM Gear__c
                             WHERE Tool__r.Opportunity__c IN : oppIds AND FinishDate__c >=: Date.TODAY()];
List<Date> neededToolsOutDates = new List<Date>();

for(Gear__c actualGear: actualGears){
    Date gearOutDate = Date.newinstance(actualGear.FinishDate__c.year(), actualGear.FinishDate__c.month(), actualGear.FinishDate__c.day());
    List<Tool__c> neededTools = opportunitiesMap.get(actualGear.Tool__r.Opportunity__c).Tools__r;
    for(Tool__c neededTool: neededTools){
        Date toolInDate = Date.newinstance(neededTool.StartDate__c.year(), neededTool.StartDate__c.month(), neededTool.StartDate__c.day());
        neededToolsOutDates.add(toolInDate);

        if(gearOutDate == toolInDate && actualGear.Clients__c != String.valueOf(neededTool.Clients__c)){
            actualGear.Clients__c = String.valueOf(neededTool.Clients__c);
            gearsToUpdate.add(actualGear);
        } else if(gearOutDate == toolInDate && !gearsToUpdate.contains(actualGear)){
            actualGear.Clients__c = '';
            gearsToUpdate.add(actualGear);
        }
    }
    if(!neededToolsOutDates.contains(gearOutDate)){
        actualGear.Clients__c = '';
        gearsToUpdate.add(actualGear);
    }
    neededToolsOutDates.clear();
}
if(!gearsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
    mapGears.putAll(gearsToUpdate);
    try{
        update mapGears.values();
    } catch(Exception e){
        emailErrorMessageNotification.sendErrorMessage(e.getTypeName(), e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
}
}
```

When I write like this, the catch block isn't covered:

```
@isTest static void testException(){
       triggerHelper c = new triggerHelper();
       List<Tool__c> tools = TestDataFactory.insertListTools(20);
       Exception actualException;
       try {
           c.updatingHelper(tools);
       } catch(Exception ex) {
           actualException = ex;
       }
       System.assertNotEquals(null, actualException);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you catching this exception?

Comment: It sounds like you're not testing the code you're trying to cover? We need to see more code to put everything in context.

Comment: Because I need an email notification with any error

Comment: You need to throw an exception where you are catching it (after the email notification sendMessage call). Then in your test you would use `System.assertEquals(expectedErrorMessage, e.getMessage())` inside a catch block.

Comment: I updated my class and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for exceptions like so:

Class:

```
myMethod() {
    try {
        insert new My_Custom_Object__c();
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        // process error message if you want

        // throw it
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

*Important: Test fails if an exception is not thrown by the method being tested in this basic example. It is recommended to test for other specifics such as the message for verbosity.*

```
@IsTest
private static void testException() {
    DmlException actualException;

    try {
        MyClass.myMethod();
    } catch(DmlException e) {
        actualException = e;
    }

    System.assertNotEquals(null, actualException);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help :(

Comment: Are you sure you are throwing the error in the catch? You are already handling the exception inside the method, so you will need to throw it again for the caller to catch it.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure..

Comment: Update the question with the latest code snippet where you are explicitly throwing the exception. The current snippet as of writing still only has the `sendErrorMessage` call in the catch block.

Comment: updated the code

Comment: I can see you're using some form of test data factory. Are the records created in the test data factory being created in such a way that it would violate rules?

Comment: No. All records are correct.

Comment: And I have to make wrong updating for their childs

Comment: What is happening when you run the test with the updated code?

Comment: Nothing. Catch isn't covered.

Comment: The catch is being covered if the test is passing. The assertion `System.assertNotEquals(null, actualException)` is your test. If actualException is not set, then the test would be failing.

Comment: No. Sorry. I was wrong. The `System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Same value: null` error

Comment: This would mean that your test is failing, right? Your code is not throwing an exception and working as expected given the inputs provided in your test. You should review the values you are passing into `updatingHelper` and check whether `update mapGears.values()` is actually failing.

Comment: But it can't fail in any way :) I thought your example was just for code coverage.

Comment: Haha, yes it's for generally testing for exceptions rather than coverage. Perhaps you do not need to wrap it in a try/catch and not test for an exception if your method cannot fail.

Comment: I had there an exception with wrong formula in workflow. And I found the error message only in logs. So now I'm trying to catch all possible errors and get them as email notifications. Is it possible just to cover it?

Comment: Not unless you can purposely make the method error by sending in bad input that you can guarantee will cause problems with related workflows/processes.

Comment: This particular handling pattern only works if the code within the catch block does something non-transactional like post a Platform Event. Otherwise, it's all getting rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern just isn't going to work.

```
try{
    update mapGears.values();
} catch(Exception e){
    emailErrorMessageNotification.sendErrorMessage(e.getTypeName(), e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

If you want the transaction to go through, you cannot re-throw the exception. That will cause a rollback, and the email won't get sent.

If you want the email to get sent, you have to allow the transaction to go through, which is going to leave your database in an inconsistent state because the trigger did not do its work.

You should only attempt to catch an exception in a trigger if you can *actually handle the exception* - that is, fix what is wrong. Otherwise, you should in almost all cases allow the exception to be thrown so that a user is presented with the error and you do not get bad data in your database.

One facet that can indicate that an exception handler is worthy of suspicion (although it's not a panacea) is that, as in this circumstance, you find it almost impossible to test. Here, you can't test your handler at all unless you can contrive to get your code to insert bad data. That's the only way to get coverage on this handler.

I've written a lengthy [argument](https://www.ktema.org/2020/01/05/on-not-writing-bad-exception-handlers/) on where one should not use this type of exception handler.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if there was a workflow rule error and admin didn't see it? Only I could see the problem in the logs. And I would like to send all such problems to the administrator by mail. For example, we can’t recreate the problem with workflow through apex, right?

Comment: If an error occurs, the operation initiated by the user should fail and surface the error. The user can then report the error to the admins. Ideally, of course, that failure mode should be identified in pre-production testing and fixed.

Comment: If you want to be notified any time an error occurs _without_ letting it impact your database, you'd need to look to a Platform Event-based logging framework.